# How to rebuild solr index using core reload

Tags: solr

I need to update my Solr schema frequently for testing search relevancy in my application. [This article](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#How_can_I_rebuild_my_index_from_scratch_if_I_change_my_schema.3F) says:

> One can also delete all documents, change the schema.xml file, and
>   then reload the core w/o shutting down Solr.

When I added a copyfield and followed the same approach, the changes do not reflect. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you try optimize command in the solr admin interface for the instance. I'm taking about solr 4.10.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important step from that document.

> 5. Re-Index your data.

Not all changes to schema files are reloadable dynamically.

For ex. adding a copyField requires reindexing of data.

Those changes which are considered backward compatible with the already indexed data are reloadable without the need for re-indexing.

Comment: I am following the approach in which solr need not be restarted which is mentioned after that 5th comment. So the question is, if I change solr schema and follow the approach where it mentions reloading the core, will it not reindex the core ?

Comment: No, reloading the core will not reindex the documents.